# How to save an array of 10,000 public keys on an account

Tags: anchor, account, program

Is there a scalable way to save an array of public keys ? I'm building a raffle type of system using Anchor framework, where we would want to save all public keys in an array, so we can pick a winner randomly from the array.

I've seen some information about zero copy, but have no knowledge on how to use it, or if it even allows for saving more than 10MB in a single account.

I would love any help around this, and if possible some code samples. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably too much of a design question than a technical issue question for you to get a real answer here tbh. You can't store more than 10mb in an account and each pubkey is 32 bytes. Accessing the index of a large zero copy array is something you probably have to figure out for yourself or pay someone to write the code for.